# JS: Counter decrease, at hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a normal

```
 <?php echo "Today (".mysql_num_rows($query)."); ?>
```

That turns out as Today (10) if there's 10 rows.

Now under this counter I have an while() that outputs all the rows inside a `<tr>`.

In a `<td>` inside the tr i have this delete button, which hides closest 'tr'.

How can I when you hide the 'tr' the Today(10) will decrease to Today(9) ?

--

I dont think its possible with the current counter (mysql_num_rows), but maybe if you count how many 'tr' there is, in the Today(), you could make something that decreases, but I do not know how to do this. Although this is just an thought..

Comment: The two options you have is using Ajax (unless you're okay with manually decreasing the number using JS), and refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
$('.deleteButton').click(function() {
   var curn = parseInt($('.counter').text(), 10);
   if(curn - 1 >= 0)
      $('.counter').text(curn - 1); 
});
```

and change your echo to

```
 <?php echo "Today (<span class='counter'>".mysql_num_rows($query)."</span>)"; ?>
```

Comment: Never forget the radix parameter in the `parseInt` function: `parseInt(num, 10);`

Comment: Great catch, I awalys forget that one :)

Comment: That was nice, thank you. Could you how the code works, as i would like to learn

Comment: Basically, when deteleButton is clicked, we get the text from the counter parse it to be an integer and update the counter again with the new value (which is curn - 1)

Comment: And what does , 10 means in the integer?

Comment: ParseInt definition: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp (10 is the radix, The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a decimal number.)

Comment: It specifies the radix (base) to use: As an example of what can go wrong: `parseInt('08'); //0`, where-as `parseInt('08', 10); //8`.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your PHP accordingly:

```
<?php echo 'Today (<span class="counter">' . mysql_num_rows($query) . '</span>)'; ?>
```

And have something like this for your delete button:

```
$('#theTable').delegate('button.delete', 'click', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').slideUp();

    $('span.counter').text(function (index, val) {
        return (parseInt(val, 10) - 1);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Note the use of [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate): It's much more efficient than it would be to [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind) an event handler to each delete button.

You'll have to alter the selector for your table and your delete button accordingly.

Comment: Just a note: `.slideUp()` doesn't work properly on table rows. And it would be nicer if you called `$(this).remove()` in the callback of `.slideUp()`, that way the element would actually be removed and not just hidden. :)

Comment: @Tatu: Didn't know about slideUp not working on rows! What a shame ;-;. I chose not to `.remove()` the row incase it has the possibility of getting shown again!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the number so you can select is easily:

```
<?php echo 'Today (<span id="number">'.mysql_num_rows($query).'</span>)'; ?>
```

Then when a delete button is clicked:

```
// Get the number element once
var num = $('#number');

// Set an onclick event on your button
$('.delete').click(function(){

    // Find the closest table row and remove it
    $(this).closest( 'tr' ).remove();

    // num.text() will get the text inside the number element
    // parseInt is used to convert it from string to int
    // subtract 1 to update the number
    var newNumber = parseInt( num.text(), 10 ) - 1;

    // And set the new number text
    num.text( newNumber );

    // Stop the default browser action - might cause the page to reload or to scroll
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Output your counter to a JavaScript var and use it in your loop and Today() function call. I'm assuming you're trying to output a client side function call from the server?

```
 <?php echo "var count=".mysql_num_rows($query).";Today(count);" ?>
```

In your delete handler decrement count and call *Today(count)* again.

Answer (score 0):

try it at: http://jsfiddle.net/xMZgv/7/

```
Today(<span id="counter">3</span>)

<table>
    <tr><td>hello</td><td>delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td>world</td><td>delete</td></tr>
    <tr><td>hi</td><td>delete</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function() {
        $('table tr').find('td:last').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            $('#counter').html($('#counter').html() - 1)
        })
    })

</script>
```